# Изменить стандартный попап при нахождении адреса

Tags: yandex-maps-api

есть ли метод, который позволит изменить данное окно, которое выводится при нахождении адреса на карте?

[image: стандартный попап]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, через публичный API эта плашка не меняется.

Comment: а через какой API меняется? со стороны разработчиков?

Answer (score 0):

ладно, найти способ изменить это у меня не получилось, но есть возможность его просто отключить, передав в опции поиска noPlacemark: true